# Magento Uploaded Image displays previous uploaded images

Tags: image, magento, upload, admin, backend

I'm having a problem. When I try to upload an image for a product, the newly uploaded image would show up to be some of the previous uploaded image when I move the mouse over it.

But when I save the product and move the mouse over the image again, it shows the correct image that was just uploaded.

I first thought it was a cache problem, so I cleaned up everything, flash, browser, magento image cache, but the problem still exists.
What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the contents of the following folder :
`\media\catalog\product\cache`
 Then reload the page to check

Comment: Thanks for the help but problem still exists. The link to the new image (Just uploaded image) seem to be correct but needs a force reload to show the correct image.